# How the NPP_NewStream of NPAPI wall called? Automatically or by a plugin-request?

Tags: c++, dll, google-chrome, plugins, npapi

I have read a lots document on NPAPI but I still do not understand:
How the `NPP_NewStream` of `NPAPI`  wall called? Automatically by Browser, whenever it load a page, an image, an video,.... or manually by our plugin-request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be called as a result of both:

- automically for e.g. `src` attributes or for full-page plugin-instances
- by plugin-request as a result of e.g. calling `NPN_GetURL()`